# Parent class notified if child class properties change

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have to view ViewModels, OrganizationContact and PersonalInformationModel.

OrganizationContact uses PersonalInformationModel.

They are setup like so:

**OrganizationContact:**

```
public class OrganizationContact : ViewModelBase
{
    private PersonalInformationModel _contactInfo;

    public PersonalInformationModel ContactInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _contactInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            _contactInfo = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ContactHeader), "", "", true);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ContactInfo), null, _contactInfo, true);
        }
    }

    //Generate Header
    public string ContactHeader
    {
        get
        {
            var header = "";

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactInfo.Title?.TitleAbbreviation))
            {
                header += ContactInfo.Title.TitleAbbreviation + " ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactInfo.FirstName))
            {
                header += ContactInfo.FirstName + " ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactInfo.MiddleInitial))
            {
                header += ContactInfo.MiddleInitial + ". ";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactInfo.LastName))
            {
                header += ContactInfo.LastName + " ";
            }

            return header;
        }
    }

    public int OrganizationLink { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

**PersonalInformationModel:**

```
public class PersonalInformationModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _middleInitial;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _phoneNumber;
    private string _phoneExtension;
    private string _faxNumber;
    private string _email;

    public int PersonalIdentity { get; set; }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName), "", _firstName, true);
        }
    }

    public string MiddleInitial
    {
        get
        {
            return _middleInitial;
        }
        set
        {
            _middleInitial= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MiddleInitial),"",_middleInitial,true);
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LastName), "", _lastName, true);
        }
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _phoneNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PhoneNumber), "", _phoneNumber, true);
        }
    }

    public string PhoneExtension
    {
        get
        {
            return _phoneExtension;
        }
        set
        {
            _phoneExtension = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PhoneExtension), "", _phoneExtension, true);
        }
    }

    public string FaxNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _faxNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _faxNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FaxNumber), "", _faxNumber, true);
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return _email;
        }
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Email),"",_email, true);
        }
    }

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

PersonalInformationModel is used by other classes.

What I'm looking for is a way for `OrganizationContact` to be informed if any property inside of `PersonalInformationModel` changes so the `ContactHeader` inside of `OrganizationContact` can be notified of the change.

Comment: Have you looked into `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: PersonalInformationModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, then you can add an event listener to OrganizationContact. Just make sure when you set the value of ContactInfo that you unregister your listener(s) and re-register them on the new value.

Comment: Yes, it is implemented within the `RaisePropertyChanged`.

Comment: You have to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event in the base class to be notified, or override the `OnPropertyChanged` method.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll, I am confused as to what you mean by unregister.

Comment: I mean: `_contactInfo.PropertyChanged -= myHandler;` right before `_contactInfo = value;` in your setter. Of course you don't have to do this if you like memory leaks :)

Comment: @RonBeyer Nope that's not what I meant. I'm talking about removing subscribers from the instance that is about to be unset in the setter, in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Sorry, I assumed one class inherited from the other, I missed that it was a member, not a child.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll, my apologies... I was ignorant to the differences between 'member' and 'child'. I am trying to be notified if a derived class has any properties change.

Comment: That's not what your question indicates: `"What I'm looking for is a way for OrganizationContact to be informed if any property inside of PersonalInformationModel changes so the ContactHeader inside of OrganizationContact can be notified of the change."`

Comment: @BrianDriscoll, Yes. So if the `FirstName` object located in the `ContactInfo` class changes I want that change to be known to the `ContactHeader` object located in the `OrganizationContact` so it can be notified to change. I'm no good with the jargon associated with OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so to get what you want you'll need to do a few things. First, register a PropertyChanged handler when you set your ContactInfo property on OrganizationContact:

```
public PersonalInformationModel ContactInfo
{
    get
    {
        return _contactInfo;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_contactInfo != null)
        {
           _contactInfo.PropertyChanged -= ContactInfo_PropertyChanged;
        }

        _contactInfo = value;

        if (_contactInfo != null)
        {
           _contactInfo.PropertyChanged += ContactInfo_PropertyChanged
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ContactInfo), null, _contactInfo, true);
    }
}
```

Now, create your handler. You should be able to just raise the PropertyChanged event on ContactHeader to update your bindings.

```
void ContactInfo_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ContactHeader), "", "", true);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why you destroy then create the Event? (I don't know if my terminology is correct)

Comment: It's purely for memory management purposes. The garbage collector will not collect your old PersonalInformationModel instance if it has a event handler belonging to a "live" listener attached to its PropertyChanged event. So, before you set a new value for _contactInfo in your setter, you want to remove any event listeners you have attached to it.